# Passing split as parameter to splice

Tags: perl

I need the first two names only in a string.

`my $myNames = "Jacob, Michael, Joshua, Matthew, Ethan, Andrew";`

`my $meNewNames = join ( ',',splice( split(/,/,$myNames), 0, 2));`

Please rectify me if anything wrong in it or we can achive it in another way.

`print "$meNewNames\n";`

It throws the error.
Type of arg 1 to splice must be array (not split)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, like the error says, the first argument must be an array. The possible solutions:

```
my $meNewNames = join ( ',',splice( [ split(/,/,$myNames) ], 0, 2));
```

Make an anonymous array reference out of your split return values. However, this only works in perl version 5.14 and up. You can do it more simply like this:

```
my $meNewNames = join ( ',', (split(/,/,$myNames))[0,1] );
```

Use a subscript to take the first two values of your split. In this style, it is perhaps more readable to do:

```
my @names = split /,\s*/, $myNames;
my $meNewNames = join ',', @names[0,1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Used your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: It is worth noting that the first option requires Perl v5.14 or later

Comment: @Borodin Indeed. I was going to mention that, but did not know the version number. Do you know of a handy place to look up such version information?

Comment: @TLP: No I don't. I just googled "perl splice array reference"

Comment: @Zaid Yes, I am aware of those documents. I was thinking more along the lines of a page which lists various features and with which perl version they came.

Comment: +1: I ran in to this issue today while writing a [perl answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202711/970195) using 5.8.8. `splice` won't take anonymous array ref as first input, so had to wrap it around `@{[..]}`. Good to know that it was introduced with 5.14.

Comment: @JS웃 It is marked as "highly experimental", so I would continue to use real arrays. Note that in your question, you can use a subscript instead of `splice`.

Comment: Thanks @TLP. Good point. I made it more complex then it should have been. Updated the answer to include subscript. (OP is probably going to disregard the `perl` answer but was a good learning practice.`:)`). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler:

```
my $meNewNames = join ( ',', (split(/,/,$myNames))[0,1] );
```

Also, you can use a regexpr instead of join / split:

```
$myNames =~ m!(\w+, *\w+)!;
# $1 => Jacob, Michael;
```

Comment: +1 agree, `splice` has a lot of unintended connotations/side-effects, because he's not actually modifying an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving an anonymous list to `split`, but you really need a real array.
Here's one way of fixing this:

```
   my @array = split(/,/,$myNames);
   my $meNewNames = join ( ',',splice( @array, 0, 2));
```