# sort a field in ascending order and delete the first and last number

Tags: python, awk

I have a data that looks like following:

```
a     10,5,3,66,50
b     2,10,1,88,5,8,9
c     4,60,10,39,55,22
d     1,604,3,503,235,45,60,7
e     20,59,33,2,6,45,36,34,22
```

I want to sort the data in second column in ascending order

```
a     3,5,10,50,66
b     1,2,5,8,9,10,88
c     4,10,22,39,55,60
....
....
```

Then delete the smallest and the largest value from it. So like this:

```
a     5,10,50
b     2,5,8,9,10
c     10,22,39,55
....
....
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can write a software program to do that for you. Then run the program.

Comment: Cool data. Is it a text file? A CSV? Do you read it in already? What do you have so far?

Comment: it is a text file. I am still trying to figure out how to ascend the data within a cell. I am not sure how to even search for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python:

```
with open('the_file.txt', 'r') as fin, open('result.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        f0, f1 = line.split() 
        fout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (f0, ','.join(sorted(f1.split(','), key=int)[1:-1])))
```

The body of the loop can be unpacked as:

```
        f0, f1 = line.split()           # split fields on whitespace
        items = f1.split(',')           # split second field on commas
        items = sorted(items, key=int)  # or items.sort(key=int) # sorts items as int
        items = items[1:-1]             # get rid of first and last items
        f1 = ','.join(items)            # reassemble field as csv
        line = '%s\t%s\n' % (f0, f1)    # reassemble line
        fout.write(line)                # write it out
```

Comment: You can also use: `f1 = sorted(f1.split(','), key=int)[1:-1]`

Comment: If you have unknown amount of spaces between your "index" and the data you could use regex like: re.split('\s\W+', line)

Comment: @IanLaird:  `str.split` is up to the task:  `'  blue  \t \r    1,2\n'.split()` gives `['blue', '1,2']`.

Comment: You are right, I just realized i was passing str.split(d, ' ').

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
awk '{l=split($2,a,",");asort(a);printf "%s\t",$1;for(i=2;i<l;i++) printf "%s"(i==l-1?RS:","),a[i]}' t
a       5,10,50
b       2,5,8,9,10
c       10,22,39,55
d       3,7,45,60,235,503
e       6,20,22,33,34,36,45
```

PS If I remember correct, you need `gnu awk` due to `asort`

How it works:

```
awk '
    {l=split($2,a,",")                      # Split the data into array "a" and set "l" to length of array
    asort(a)                                # Sort the array "a"
    printf "%s\t",$1                        # Print the first column
    for(i=2;i<l;i++)                        # Run a loop from second element to second last element in array "a"
        printf "%s"(i==l-1?RS:","),a[i]     # Print the element separated by "," except for last element, print a new line
    }'  file                                # Read the file
```

Comment: You can use return value of `split` or `asort` and use that in `for loop` instead of using `length(a)` function. Also in the `ternary op` you can do `?"\n":","` and skip the `print ""`.

Comment: @JS웃 Hi, thanks for the info, post updated.  Just modified a post I found using google :).  PS I think `RS` is better than `"\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is an alternate solution using `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'\s+|,' -lane '
print $F[0] . "\t" . join "," , splice @{[sort { $a<=>$b } @F[1..$#F]]} , 1, $#F-2' file
a       5,10,50
b       2,5,8,9,10
c       10,22,39,55
d       3,7,45,60,235,503
e       6,20,22,33,34,36,45
```

or with newer versions of `perl` you can drop the `@{..}` and say:

```
perl -F'\s+|,' -lane '
    print $F[0] . "\t" . join "," , splice [sort { $a<=>$b } @F[1..$#F]] , 1, $#F-2
' file
```

or just use sub-script:

```
perl -F'\s+|,' -lane '
    print $F[0] . "\t" . join "," , ( sort { $a<=>$b }@F[1..$#F] ) [1..$#F-2]
' file
```

Comment: Nice one! (Note that you can omit the `@{ .. }` in the `splice` command. Just use `splice [sort { $a<=>$b } @F[1..$#F]] , 1, $#F-2`.)

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland, the first argument to `splice` should be an array so it won't take the anonymous array unless you dereference it.

Comment: Actually I think the square brackets produce an array reference, see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html .. That's why you don't need to dereference it..

Comment: @HåkonHægland This is the error you'll get if you don't put `@{..}` - `Type of arg 1 to splice must be array (not anonymous list ([]))..`

Comment: Maybe its related to the version of perl then? This command: `perl -F'\s+|,' -lane 'print join "," , splice [sort { $a<=>$b } @F[1..$#F]] , 1, $#F-2' file` works fine for me. I am using perl version 5.14.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Hmm, probably. I have an old version of `perl v5.8.8`. Thanks for the great feedback though. Looks like it was fixed in the newer release.

Answer (score 0):

Full python example. This assumes your data is in a text file. You would call it like this.

```
./parser.py filename
```

Or you could pipe it together like this:

```
echo 'a    3,2,1,4,5' | ./parser.py -
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/env python
import argparse
import sys

def splitAndTrim(d):
    line = str.split(d)
    arr = sorted(map(int, line[1].split(',')))
    print("{0}    {1}".format(line[0], ",".join(map(str, arr[1:-1]))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('FILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    for line in args.FILE:
        splitAndTrim(line)
```

Comment: No need to convert to from `str` to `int` to `str` if you use a `key=int` argument on `sorted`.  Also, if you really wanted to go whole hog, capture the whitespace in your regular expression and then reuse it on the output.

Comment: Thanks for the regex suggestion. the map to int is still required as it is stripping off a training '\n' in the input data.  But i think the split realization you gave me sorta negates the need for the regex all together.

Comment: `str.split(d)` is the same as `d.split()`